# Avoid HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type when Accept header is missing

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, http, http-headers

I need to be able to handle requests with missing Accept header. I am using a `WebHostBuilder` (and `ApiController`s). The application is an old MVC application migrated to .NET Core. I somehow can't find an appropriate place in the `WebHostBuilder` to add a header if it is missing... or do something else that would allow the request to be processed as if it had the header. Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of request is coming ? JSON or xml or something else?

Comment: Just an empty Get request

Comment: What is the Content-Type coming from client?

Comment: There is no content type coming from the client. And I really don't care about the missing headers and just want to forward the request to the controller.

Comment: It will be good if you can post your code or part of it. Since, with .Net Core are you on 3.0 or 2.2? With code, it will be easy to identify it. Do you have Consume attr on action?

Comment: I don't have any `Consumes` attributes, why should I when I don't expect any content... I am on 2.1.3 with WebApiCompatShim. I can't post code... and I don't see what the need is, when I just have standard `WebHostBuilder` stuff.